# How to ungroup columns and cells in OpenPyXL

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

With the worksheets column_dimensions.group it is possible to group columns and cells. However, I am not able to find any method to ungroup columns or rows?

```
ws.column_dimensions.group('A','D')
```

Is there any ungroup method in OpenPyXL 2.6.2, or do I have to reset the formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ws.column_dimensions.group('A','D', outline_level=0)
```

Comment: please add more explanation

Answer (score 0):

The tables are list elements in ws._tables. To ungroup all you can try

```
ws._tables = []
```